# git bundle from stash divergence point up to stash

Tags: git

I want to create a git bundle that contains just the commits in my stash that aren't in the point the stash is based off of. I want to do this as opposed to sending every single commit ever made, since I know the recipient already has every commit up to and including the divergence point.

I am getting this:

```
$ git bundle create ehhh stash...master^1
fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.
```

...which makes no sense, as `git rev-list stash...master^1` returns two commits.

Am I not understanding the tool or is this a limitation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the treeish stash...master^1 isn't interpreted correctly by bundle. A workaround is to create a tag:

```
git tag bundle_end master^1
git bundle create ehhh stash...bundle_end
```

Note that treeish range specifiers retrieve all commits *since* the beginning, not including the beginning commit itself.

Comment: That didn't work either, same problem. I think you already know but just making sure: stash's parent is master^. git rev-list stash...bundle_end lists the stash and its index as expected. I ended up applying my stash to a public branch on the repo (the insecure path of least resistance), though my plans to takeover the world were in there (this is why I wanted to bundle, so that info would be private to the recipient). Sorry if the world is destroyed because someone else obtains my plans now.